# React Native get return value of async function

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

I am trying to get pub locations data from MYSQL server and my fetch function works well. But after that, this try-catch block does not return anything. I also tried without try-catch block but it does not change anything

```
  getPubsFromDatabase = async () => {
    let response = await fetch(fetchDataUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: 
      {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    try{
      let json = await response.json();
      console.log(json)
      return json;
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

And here, I am trying to get the return value of the function. But in this version, I cannot even see any console.log output. What I mean by the version is, if I put 2nd line out of the async block without "await" keyword, I can see the console.log but I it gives "undefined" then.

```
  (async () => {
    const locationsData = await getPubsFromDatabase();
    console.log(locationsData)
  })()
```

Comment: Hello. What is the output of `console.log(json)`?

Comment: Just wrap your async function in a useEffect

Comment: @MatthewHerbst It doesnt print that. I think the problem is in the place where I call the function. That part is never activated and function is not called.

Comment: @miknoup thank you for suggestion but I tried it. It still doesn't call the function

Answer (score 0):

You can use **then** and **catch** in the function **fetch**.

```js
  const getPubsFromDatabase = () => {
    return fetch(fetchDataUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: 
      {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    }).then(async (response) => {
      const json = await response.json().then((data)=>{
        return data;
      }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log('error from json method: ',err);
        return  { error: {
         message: 'error from json method',
         object: err
        }};
      });
      console.log(json);
      return json;
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('error from request: ', error);
      return  {
        error: {
          message: 'error from request', object: error
        }
      };
    });
  }
```

And when you use the method **getPubsFromDatabase** would be of the next way:

```js
  (async () => {
    const locationsData = await getPubsFromDatabase();
    console.log(locationsData);
  })()
```

Comment: I tried this but I still cannot get any print. I think my function works but the problem is in the part that I am calling it. Because app acts like that I did not even call the function and does not print any console.log. Not even "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promise to return either result or error, In the example given below i have used axios library but you can also try same with fetch api
For Example

```
export const getData = () => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const url = ApiConstant.BASE_URL + ApiConstant.ENDPOINT;
    const API_HEADER = {
      "Authorization": token,
    };

    axios
      .get(url, {
        headers: API_HEADER,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        resolve(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // handle error
        reject(error);
        console.log(error);
      });
  })
}
```

You can call the above function in component or screen like this:

```
getData().then(
            (data) => {

            }
        ).catch(
            error => {
                console.log(error)
            }
        )
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it gives "TypeError: Promise is not a function (near '...})((0, _asyncToGenerat...')" error on the "getData().then..." part. I think my function works but the problem is in the part that I am calling it. Because app acts like that I did not call the function and does not print any console.log. Not even "undefined"

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to remove type "any" from getData().then(
            (data: any) => {}

Comment: Yes I fixed it before but it didn't solve the error. But I found another way to solve the problem. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by instead of returning the value from the function, I set the value inside the function. This seems to work now.

```
  const [locationsData, setLocationsData] = useState();
  getPubsFromDatabase = async () => {
    let response = await fetch(fetchDataUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: 
      {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    try{
      let json = await response.json();
      setLocationsData(json); // Here, I changed the value of the locationsData instead of returning
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

And to call the function:

```
  useEffect(()=> {
    getPubsFromDatabase();
  },[])
```